# Chrome for mobile input field maxlength behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome, mobile

I've noticed that when using the maxLength attribute on an input field, Chrome for mobile will allow more characters than the maxLength to be entered, then cut back to the max length amount when the field loses focus.

Chrome for mobile is the only browser that I've seen exhibit this particular behaviour.

This has been raised by our QA team as a bug on a mobile app that we're developing, and although we could enforce it using JavaScript, we're hesitant to go down that route for various reasons.

Is there an easy way to change this behaviour, or is it a hack it or live with it thing?

Comment: sounds weird.  I would prob put down a JS script to enforce it.  Somewith lenght() on the value, but yea i understand your issue with that solution :)

Comment: It's not just mobile; Chromium for Windows has this problem, too.
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129801

Comment: Thanks for that link Golphy, hopefully that'll help placate the QA team a bit :)